# Adding image to PyQT without QRC file

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I used Designer to create the layout for my gui. I need to be able to have QLabel that is part of the main GUI cycle through a couple of different, newly-created images while the GUI is running. There must be a way to do this, right? Whenever I look up how to do that, I only find ways to add an image to Designer, then pyrrc the qrc file, and you know the drill. But there must be a way to add an image while avoiding all that.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, actually. Find the label you want. Let us say the label is label_1. Then, in your MainDialog class (or wherever), use QPixmap like this:

```
self.label_1.setPixmap(QPixmap("img.jpg"))
```

That should work. Good luck!